# Tumblr submit photo

Tags: jquery, json, share, tumblr

Is there a way a can submit a photo to someone's tumblr (for them to review) from another website. maybe a json request or something similar.

Comment: Does [Tumblr’s API documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posting) help?

Comment: self answered. you can create an iframe

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="post-wrapper clearfix">
  <section class="post">
     <div class="body-text">
         <p><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="427" id="submit_form" src="http://www.tumblr.com/submit_form/blogsname.tumblr.com" style="background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;"></iframe><!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('submit_form').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]--></p>
      </div>
   </section>
 </div>
```

Comment: Nice, can I ask where you found out about this, just for reference?

Comment: their API. im still trying to make a stand alone JSON response that can send a picture. will post when i get it done